# Doctrine cannot map association

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

The scenario is: User is one to one association to Brother and brother can block other brother.

Then I cannot map BrotherHasBrotherBlocked#brother as identifier, because the target entity Brother also maps an association as identifier, but I every entity must have an identifier and I don't know how to get rid of this mapping fail.

Mapped entities below:

Entity User:

```
App\Domain\Model\User\User:
    type: entity
    table: user
    id:
        id:
            type: integer
            nullable: false
            options:
                unsigned: true
            id: true
            generator:
                trategy: IDENTITY
    fields:
        ...
    oneToOne:
        brother:
            targetEntity: App\Domain\Model\User\Brother\Brother
            cascade: ["persist"]
            fetch: LAZY
            mappedBy: user
            joinColumns:
                user_id:
                    referencedColumnName: id
            orphanRemoval: false
```

Entity Brother

```
App\Domain\Model\User\Brother\Brother:
    type: entity
    table: brother
    id:
        user:
            associationKey: true
    fields:
        ...
    oneToOne:
        user:
            targetEntity: App\Domain\Model\User\User
            cascade: ["persist"]
            fetch: LAZY
            inversedBy: brother
            joinColumns:
                id:
                    referencedColumnName: id
            orphanRemoval: false
    oneToMany:
        brothersBlocked:
            targetEntity: App\Domain\Model\User\Brother\BrotherHasBrotherBlocked
            mappedBy: brother
            cascade: ["persist"]
```

Entity BrotherHasBrotherBlocked

```
App\Domain\Model\User\Brother\BrotherHasBrotherBlocked:
    type: entity
    table: brother_has_brother_blocked
    id:
        brother:
            associationKey: true
        brotherBlocked:
            associationKey: true
    fields:
        ...
    manyToOne:
        brother:
            targetEntity:  App\Domain\Model\User\Brother\Brother
            cascade: ["persist"]
            inversedBy: brothersBlocked
            joinColumns:
                brother_id:
                    referencedColumnName: id
            orphanRemoval: false
        brotherBlocked:
            targetEntity:  App\Domain\Model\User\Brother\Brother
            cascade: ["persist"]
            inversedBy: brothersBlocked
            joinColumns:
                brother_blocked_id:
                    referencedColumnName: id
            orphanRemoval: false
    lifecycleCallbacks: {  }
```

Running: bin/console doctrine:schema:validate

> ### Mapping
>
> [FAIL] The entity-class
>   App\Domain\Model\User\Brother\BrotherHasBrotherBlocked mapping is
>   invalid:
>   * Cannot map association 'App\Domain\Model\User\Brother\BrotherHasBrotherBlocked#brother as
>   identifier, because the target entity
>   'App\Domain\Model\User\Brother\Brother' also maps an association as
>   identifier.
>   * Cannot map association 'App\Domain\Model\User\Brother\BrotherHasBrotherBlocked#brotherBlocked
>   as identifier, because the target entity
>   'App\Domain\Model\User\Brother\Brother' also maps an association as
>   identifier.
>   * The mappings App\Domain\Model\User\Brother\BrotherHasBrotherBlocked#brotherBlocked
>   and App\Domain\Model\User\Brother\Brother#brothersBlocked are
>   inconsistent with each other.

I wanted to check the do validation after the associated relation gets an integer instead of the correct entity type. This error came up after I stored associated relations once successfuly and later tried the same request and got this unexpected type error for one of the associated relations I'm targeting here

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that brother use `mappedBy: brother`
but both brother and brother blocked use `inversedBy: brothersBlocked`

You can remove `inversedBy: brothersBlocked` from brotherBlocked without any errors.

Or you can add a `blockedBy` property to your `Brother` entity with mappedBy `brothersBlocked` and for `brothersBlocked` add `inversedBy: blockedBy`

So you will have:
Entity Brother

```
App\Domain\Model\User\Brother\Brother:
    type: entity
    table: brother
    id:
        user:
            associationKey: true
    fields:
        ...
    oneToOne:
        user:
            targetEntity: App\Domain\Model\User\User
            cascade: ["persist"]
            fetch: LAZY
            inversedBy: brother
            joinColumns:
                id:
                    referencedColumnName: id
            orphanRemoval: false
    oneToMany:
        brothersBlocked:
            targetEntity: App\Domain\Model\User\Brother\BrotherHasBrotherBlocked
            mappedBy: brotherBlocked
            cascade: ["persist"] 
        blockedBy:
            targetEntity: App\Domain\Model\User\Brother\BrotherHasBrotherBlocked
            mappedBy: brother
            cascade: ["persist"]
```

Entity BrotherHasBrotherBlocked

```
App\Domain\Model\User\Brother\BrotherHasBrotherBlocked:
    type: entity
    table: brother_has_brother_blocked
    id:
        brother:
            associationKey: true
        brotherBlocked:
            associationKey: true
    fields:
        ...
    manyToOne:
        brother:
            targetEntity:  App\Domain\Model\User\Brother\Brother
            cascade: ["persist"]
            inversedBy: brothersBlocked
            joinColumns:
                brother_id:
                    referencedColumnName: id
            orphanRemoval: false
        brotherBlocked:
            targetEntity:  App\Domain\Model\User\Brother\Brother
            cascade: ["persist"]
            inversedBy: blockedBy
            joinColumns:
                brother_blocked_id:
                    referencedColumnName: id
            orphanRemoval: false
    lifecycleCallbacks: {  }
```

Comment: For proposed solution 1: BrotherHasBrotherBlocked entity must contain the required inversedBy. For solution 2: I still get the same error about inconsistency with each other shown in my question before. None of them solved the mapping issue

Comment: Could you please remove all the cache `rm -rf var/cache/*/*` and then call your code  and copy the exact error?